# Javascript Breaks Selenium Tests

Tags: java, javascript, selenium

I am currently writing a basic Selenium test for a company I am an intern at, and this error have been bugging me for a while now. If I turn Javascript off on my test, it goes through fine, but as soon as I turn on Javascript for the test, it never completes.

The test looks like this:

```
public void Login()
{
    driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
    driver.get("https://127.0.0.1:4433");

    WebElement usernamefield = driver.findElement(By.id("username"));
    WebElement passwordfield = driver.findElement(By.id("password"));
    usernamefield.sendKeys(email);
    passwordfield.sendKeys(password);
    WebElement loginButton = driver.findElement(By.className("jsLoginSubmit"));
    loginButton.click();
    driver.navigate().to("https://127.0.0.1:4433/?op=caselist");
    assertTrue(driver.getTitle().contains("Overblik")
            && driver.getTitle().contains(userid.toString()));
    System.out.println(email);
    driver.close();
}
```

This test works just fine if Javascript is disabled. I am using this to instantiate the driver in my `setUp()` method:

```
driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
```

But here is the output from running the test with Javascript enabled:

```
09:40:35,162 ERROR StrictErrorReporter:79 - runtimeError: message=[The data necessary to complete this operation is not yet available.] sourceName=[https://127.0.0.1:4433/static/lib/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js] line=[2] lineSource=[null] lineOffset=[0]
09:40:35,470  WARN DefaultCssErrorHandler:39 - CSS error: [21:23] Error in style rule. Invalid token ":". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", <COMMA>, ";", "/", <PLUS>, "-", <HASH>, <STRING>, <URI>, "!", "inherit", <EMS>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <DIMENSION>, <PERCENTAGE>, <NUMBER>, <FUNCTION>, <IDENT>.
09:40:35,471  WARN DefaultCssErrorHandler:53 - CSS warning: [21:23] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
09:40:35,502  WARN DefaultCssErrorHandler:39 - CSS error: [148:23] Error in style rule. Invalid token ":". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", <COMMA>, ";", "/", <PLUS>, "-", <HASH>, <STRING>, <URI>, "!", "inherit", <EMS>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <DIMENSION>, <PERCENTAGE>, <NUMBER>, <FUNCTION>, <IDENT>.
09:40:35,503  WARN DefaultCssErrorHandler:53 - CSS warning: [148:23] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
09:40:35,509  WARN DefaultCssErrorHandler:39 - CSS error: [163:23] Error in style rule. Invalid token ":". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", <COMMA>, ";", "/", <PLUS>, "-", <HASH>, <STRING>, <URI>, "!", "inherit", <EMS>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <DIMENSION>, <PERCENTAGE>, <NUMBER>, <FUNCTION>, <IDENT>.
09:40:35,510  WARN DefaultCssErrorHandler:53 - CSS warning: [163:23] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
09:40:35,512  WARN DefaultCssErrorHandler:39 - CSS error: [182:23] Error in style rule. Invalid token ":". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", <COMMA>, ";", "/", <PLUS>, "-", <HASH>, <STRING>, <URI>, "!", "inherit", <EMS>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <DIMENSION>, <PERCENTAGE>, <NUMBER>, <FUNCTION>, <IDENT>.
09:40:35,513  WARN DefaultCssErrorHandler:53 - CSS warning: [182:23] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
09:40:35,516  WARN DefaultCssErrorHandler:39 - CSS error: [201:23] Error in style rule. Invalid token ":". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", <COMMA>, ";", "/", <PLUS>, "-", <HASH>, <STRING>, <URI>, "!", "inherit", <EMS>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <DIMENSION>, <PERCENTAGE>, <NUMBER>, <FUNCTION>, <IDENT>.
09:40:35,516  WARN DefaultCssErrorHandler:53 - CSS warning: [201:23] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
```

I don't know what this means, and I can't seem to find a solution or reason as to why this happens in the first place. I am turning on Javascript but it complains about CSS rules??

Anyone know how to possibly fix this?

I am using **Selenium 2.21.0**

Comment: it might be complaining about dynamic applied styles. Do you have scripts that change styles? or dynamically load stylesheets?

Comment: @MichaelDibbets When I can I will ask about that. But what impact does it make?

Comment: If it is properly testing it will run past everything triggering what it can, then it will test what will happen after that. My guess some "invalid" css is applied that might have an use case for IE or some other browser specifically.

Comment: @MichaelDibbets It's just from my understanding `new HtmlUnitDriver();` is not an actual browser driver but some sort of like, emulator? The test needs to be headless.

Comment: Yes, but styling still changes. And the styled changed should still be valid. That's what gets tested. Basically: if I press button A, B changes. is changed B still valid?

Comment: @MichaelDibbets But this is very basic. Like Javascript changing the DOM? How can this driver fail at something that is basically done all the time ._.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73743/discussion-between-michael-dibbets-and-vipar).

Comment: Selenium 2.21.0 is ancient. I'd recommend upgrading before doing anything else.